# How to copy database schema to enother database using SQL Server Compact in C#?

Tags: c#, copy, schema, sql-server-ce

I want to copy programmatically the SQL Server Compact database (.sdf file) into another database (.sdf file) using C#.

Just schema without data (I mean creating empty database with same schema)

Is it possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a empty (template) database file handy, and copy it when required.

Comment: Well, it will make me store redundant data... This method looks quite easy and evident. But what about programmatic schema copying using C# SQLServerCe classes? I can't believe tha it's not possible...

Comment: Yes, it will require some extra KBs, is that a big issue? You could also use my scripting API, but will require code, if you prefer to maintain code and fix bugs

Comment: Well you almost persuade me :) But I would rather try you scripting API - where I should look for it?

Comment: Exportsqlce.codeplex.com - use scriptdatabasetofile and executesqlfile for example